# Recover phone data from encrypted Android phone with broken screen (still being online)

Tags: adb, 7.1-nougat

my phone's touchscreen (OnePlus 3) got broken entirely yesterday (black, unresponsive, cracked => total damage!). Considering investing in a screen repair I'd really would like to know if there's any possibility for me to access my data partition. Connecting my phone under Ubuntu `adb shell` does not find any devices, since I could not unlock the device's display I guess. Is there any (Linux) way to do that?

best
Andi